# Firebase Analytics data to Redshift - BigQuery RECORD data type to Redshift

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, data-modeling, firebase-analytics

I need to export Firebase Analytics data that is currently in BigQuery to Redshift.

The issue I have is with fields in BigQuery that are of the `RECORD` data type (screenshot of the BQ schema below):

[image: Analytics for Firebase BQ schema: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512]

How would I store these key/values in Redshift? I was initially thinking of creating an `event_params` Dimension table that is linked back to the main `events` table by a UUID.

But as there are multiple key/value pairs per event, each event in the `events` table will have multiple rows in the Dimension table - which in my mind, will still be messy when running reports on the data.

How should I model this data in Redshift?

Answer (score 1):

Your data model design should be driven by your reporting requirements: how you need to report on your event parameters will inform how your model needs to be designed.

Given that caveat, if you just want to add these event parameters to an existing event star (and I assume event is a fact table with a grain of one record per event) then you would need to implement a bridge table between the event fact table and the event parameter dimension table.